# Android Studio Debug Show Error While Sync Project With Gradle Don't Show Error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

here's when I sync project with gradle, it show no error
[image: here's when I sync project with gradle, it show no error]

And this is when I want to debug it,
[image: And this is when I want to debug it,]

can anybody see the problem? I have been update the SDK 24 and gradle 2.14

Comment: What does your build.gradle look like?  Going to need more information about the configuration of your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try Cleaning and Building your project. Several errors can be fixed by doing this.